# Android - Dialog Button onClick -> EditText Value

Tags: android, dialog, onclick, android-edittext

I have a "Search" Button in my Options menu, which shows a Dialog with the Search Mask.
So when you click on the Search Button it should start the actual search.

What I'm trying to do in my onCreateDialog is:

```
Button search_button = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.d_search_button);
search_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(View v) {
    EditText text = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.d_search_text);
  }
});
```

Which won't work because text is null, so what is the best way to access the Search Text?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
final EditText text  = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.d_search_text);

   search_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View v) {

   String searchString = text.getText().toString();
    //do something
   }

});
```

Comment: I feel a bit stupid now, could have really thought of that. lol

Answer (score 2):

Make `EditText text` a final global variable. And set it when you set your event, it will then be available whenever the event fires:

```
Button search_button = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.d_search_button);
text = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.d_search_text);
search_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(View v) {
  //get your text here
  }
});
```